# database connection pooling in ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I just started with Ruby and I am playing with Sinatra, but could not find a way to share database connections between requests.

I came from Java web developement and one of the basic things you have to do is to pool the database connections, so I am sure that something similar exists in Ruby, but I just can't find it.

ActiveRecord and DataMapper offer this feature but I don't need ORM and just want to make regular SQL queries.

Is there some specific approach for Sinatra or there are general ways for all Rack-based applications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To persist a connection, you need only create an instance variable (Sinatra Applications are just objects anyway) or a global variable. Or a class that manages connections for you. Most Ruby database libraries I've seen are Database Adapters or just clients.

```
@db = Mysql2::Client.new #...
```

Or a global variable:

```
$db = Mysql2::Client.new #...
```

Connection pooling is just a way to share a small number of connections across multiple threads/fibers for the lifespan of the application. Java, the JVM, as far as I know doesn't share connections between processes.

However, there is a general purpose [Connection Pool library for Ruby](https://github.com/mperham/connection_pool).

Comment: Thanks ,but if I create an instance variable ,every time the application object is created ,new connection is created too ,right ?
So how that help with sharing connections ?

Comment: The application isn't closed between requests unless you manually close it. The application is loaded and will respond to requests and persist its connection across its lifetime. That's the best I know for connection pooling in Ruby.

Comment: It's probably a bad idea to use Mysql2 directly without some ORM like [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org), [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org) or [ActiveRecord](http://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord). These will do pooling for you automatically in most cases. If you're "just doing SQL queries" your application will quickly end up a mess. Sequel is the best choice for getting as close to SQL without actually going there as the query generator is really quite good.

Comment: @Robert K Thanks again ,could you tell me where that behavior is specified ,in the Rack standard ,Sinatra framework or just by testing ? I'm just curious.

Comment: @tadman In Java ORM tend to be very slow ,so that is the main reason because i don't use them.

Comment: @tadman The only reason it'd be bad to rely on the DB client directly is that so many people are total DB newbies today. Writing good SQL isn't hard, but it does take practice and understanding of it that most new-intermediate programmers don't seem to have.

Comment: @Nikoi, Ruby's Sequel is very well done and runs extremely fast. Take a look at it.

Comment: I'm with @theTinMan. Sequel is a good balance between fast and featured.