# Which is better in coding, one long db connection and passing the object around, or multiple short db connections?

Tags: ruby, database, dbi

I'm writing a ruby script that will be connecting to one database, in multiple tables, and I'm not sure which is better:

- Having one connection and passing the object around
- Having a connection method that I have make then return the connection back
- Having multiple connections when I need them in a method

I'm pretty new and not sure which is better/industry standard/etc.

A couple other articles on stackoverflow mentioned that connections hang around for a while in some of the other languages, is this true for anything connecting to a db or just certain languages/environments?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) object.  Ruby has a [standard module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html) for creating singletons.

You don't want the overhead of connecting to the database every time you need to run a query.  Its also not a great design pattern to pass around the connection as a parameter to every method which needs it.

For large or complex applications a common strategy is to use a [connection pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool).

Related:

- [Database Connection Pool in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993241/database-connection-pooling-in-ruby)

Comment: The app will be small so it sounds like I'll want to go with Ruby's standard library for singletons.  Thanks for the info!